# UIView's touches not being recognized

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, touchesbegan

The `touchesBegan:` is not being called by my `TextSelection` class. `TextSelection` is a UIView subclass which I added as a subview of `ReaderContentPage`, also a UIView. `ReaderContentPage` is s subview of `ReaderContentView`, a UIScrollView. And this `ReaderContentView` is inside `ReaderViewController`, a UIViewController. Here is an illustration to make it easier to understand.

[image]

Now my problem is this. `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` is not recognized in TextSelect. I enabled the userInteraction, used the UIPanGestureRecognizer, but none of those worked. Now when I tried to do this: `[self.ReadContView addSubView:txtSel]` instead of this `[self.ReadContView.ReadContPage addSubView:txtSel]`, the touches are recognized. But I have to add it in ReaderContentPage and not in ReaderContentView for some reason. So can anyone explain to me why `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` are not called when I add TextSelect in ReaderContentPage?

Comment: IS user interaction enabled for readcontpage enabled as well?

Comment: Hmm nothing is declared. Is the userInteraction disabled by default? I'll enable it and see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserInteraction is disabled by default on UIImageView, have you a UIImageView in your readContentPage?

Comment: There is no UIImageView in ReaderContentPage, but the userInteraction is disabled in it. I declared userInteraction as enabled and it finally recognized the touches. Thanks!